# Creating Nested tables and Using colspan not working Properly (Rtfwriter2 ; itext)

Tags: itext

While creating rtf files using itext an issue came up.
The cells that are using colspan are not generated properly in the output file.
Can someone help me with this.
I am attaching sample code for reference.{Can't attach image: 10 reputation needed}

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Document document = new Document( PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50 );
    try
    {
        RtfWriter2 writer = RtfWriter2.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( "/root/Desktop/TableRtf.rtf" ) );
        document.open();

        Table table1 = new Table( 3 );
        table1.setWidth( 100 );
        table1.setBorder( 0 );
        table1.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER );
        table1.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
        table1.addCell( "!" );
        table1.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table1.addCell( "!" );
        table1.addCell( "2" );
        table1.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table1.addCell( "2" );
        table1.addCell( "3" );
        table1.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table1.addCell( "3" );
        Table table = new Table( 2 );
        table.setWidth( 100 );
        table.setBorder( 0 );
        com.lowagie.text.Cell tablecell1 = new com.lowagie.text.Cell();
        tablecell1.addElement( new Chunk( "!!!!!!!!!!" ) );
        tablecell1.setColspan( 2 );
        table.addCell( tablecell1 );
        table.addCell( "Text Text Text Text Text Text " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Text Text " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Text Text Text " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Text \nText \nText " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Text " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Text " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Text " );
        table.addCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( "cell" ) ) );
        table.addCell( "Table11 " );
        table.insertTable( table1 );
        document.add( table );
    }
    catch ( Exception de )
    {
        de.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();

}
```

Comment: I've upvoted you, you can attach an image now :)

Comment: This quite a call from the past! iText doesn't support rtf for more years that I care to remember. In any case I've bumped your reputation to be able to post images.

Comment: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xiBbCSK.png" alt="Chicago commercial photographers"> Link to the Image. Thanks anyways